# Drawing finite-state automata without using VertexRenderingFunction

Tags: graphs-and-networks, labeling, automation

In the tutorial entitled "Hierarchical Drawing of Directed Graphs" in Mathematica 12, there is an example of how to draw a graph with several properties I want, but it uses an option called `VertexRenderingFunction` which is superseded by `VertexShapeFunction`:

```
LayeredGraphPlot[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 6, 6 -> 7, 
  7 -> 8, 8 -> 1, 1 -> 9, 2 -> 9, 3 -> 10, 4 -> 10, 6 -> 11, 5 -> 11, 
  7 -> 12, 8 -> 12}, Left, 
 VertexRenderingFunction -> ({EdgeForm[Black], Yellow, Disk[#1, 0.2], 
     Black, Text[#2, #1]} &)]
```

Since I'm trying to draw a finite-state automaton, I want a graph with directed arrows between nodes, where the nodes are circles containing a small number (the state number), as well as labels on the edges. I'm only trying to display acyclic automata at this point.

Trying to get `VertexShapeFunction` to do these things somehow suppressed the directed arrows; what is the proper way to do this? Ideally there would be the usual notations for the start state and final states as well. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the default vertex shape (`Disk`) and use the option `VertexLabels` (that is, no need to use `VertexShapeFunction`):

```
edges = {1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 6, 6 -> 7, 7 -> 8, 8 -> 1, 
    1 -> 9, 2 -> 9, 3 -> 10, 4 -> 10, 6 -> 11, 5 -> 11, 7 -> 12, 8 -> 12};

LayeredGraphPlot[edges, Left, 
  VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
  VertexStyle -> Yellow, 
  VertexSize -> Large]
```

[image]

If you need to use `VertexShapeFunction` you can add the option `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"`:

```
LayeredGraphPlot[edges, Left,  
   VertexShapeFunction -> ({EdgeForm[Black], Yellow, Disk[#1, 0.2], Black, Text[#2, #1]}&),
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```

[image]

**Update:** Using `DiscreteMarkovProcess` with `Graph`

```
dmp = DiscreteMarkovProcess[1, Graph[edges]];
```

Absorbing and transient nodes are automatically styled when `dmp` is used as the first argument of `Graph`:

```
g1 = SimpleGraph @ Graph[dmp, 
  GraphLayout -> {"LayeredDigraphEmbedding", "Orientation" -> Left}]
```

[image]

You can change the style of any node (say, vertex 1) using `SetProperty`:

```
SetProperty[g1, VertexStyle -> {1 -> Red}]
```

[image]